# Set default or constant value for a column in macOS Numbers

Tags: macos, apple-numbers

I am looking for a way to add default or constant value to a column in macOS Numbers?
When I want to create a new row based on previous row I should always copy and paste the values after adding which is a bit annoying.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be possible, a bit tricky though

1. add an initial value to column
2. add in the next row formula referencing cell above it
3. copy this formula to below cell using dragging (*is's important*)
4. now when you duplicate row (via popup menu, sorry I have Russian Numbers) or increasing table height you'll get automatically copied values

[image]